# K&R Exercise 1-21. Write a program `entab` that replaces strings of blanks with tabs

Tags: beginner, c, strings, formatting, io

### Intro

I'm going through the K&R book (2nd edition, ANSI C ver.) and want to get the most from it: learn (outdated) C and practice problem-solving at the same time. I believe that the author's intention was to give the reader a good exercise, to make him think hard about what he can do with the tools introduced, so I'm sticking to program features introduced so far and using "future" features and standards only if they don't change the program logic.

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99`.

### K&R Exercise 1-21

Write a program `entab` that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing. Use the same tab stops as for `detab`. When either a tab or a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given preference?

### Solution

The solution attempts to reuse functions coded in the previous exercises (`getline` & `copy`) and make the solution reusable as well. In that spirit, a new function `size_t entab(char s[], size_t tw);` is coded to solve the problem. For lines that can fit in the buffer, the solution is straightforward. However, what if they can't? The `main` routine deals with that, and most of the lines are treating the special case where we must merge the blanks from 2 `getline` calls. This exercise is just after the chapter where `extern` variables are introduced, and they really are convenient here enabling the `entab` function to be aware of the column we're at.

### Code

```
/* Exercise 1-21. Write a program `entab` that replaces strings of
 * blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same
 * spacing. Use the same tab stops as for `detab`. When either a tab or
 * a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be
 * given preference?
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXTW   4       // max. tab stop width
#define LINEBUF MAXTW   // line buffer size, must be >=MAXTW

size_t col = 0;         // current column
size_t tcol = 0;        // target column

size_t getline(char line[], size_t sz);
void copy(char * restrict to, char const * restrict from);
size_t entab(char s[], size_t tw);

int main(void)
{
    extern size_t col;                  // current column
    extern size_t tcol;                 // target column

    char line[LINEBUF];                 // input buffer
    size_t len;                         // input buffer string length

    size_t tw = 4;                      // tab width

    if (tw > MAXTW) {
        return -1;
    }

    len = getline(line, LINEBUF);
    while (len > 0) {
        len = entab(line, tw);
        if (line[len-1] == '\n') {
            // base case, working with a full, properly terminated line
            // or a tail of one; we can safely print it
            col = 0;
            tcol = 0;
            printf("%s", line);
            len = getline(line, LINEBUF);
        }
        else if (line[len-1] != ' ') {
            // could be part of a bigger line or end of stream and we
            // don't have dangling blanks; we can safely print it
            printf("%s", line);
            len = getline(line, LINEBUF);
        }
        else {
            // we have some dangling blanks and must peek ahead to
            // know whether we can merge them into a tab or not
            bool cantab = false;
            char pline[LINEBUF];    // peek buffer
            size_t plen;            // peek buffer string length
            plen = getline(pline, LINEBUF);
            if (plen > 0) {
                if (pline[0] == ' ') {
                    // count spaces in the peek; pspc = 1 because if
                    // we're here then we already know pline[0] == ' '
                    size_t pspc;
                    for (pspc = 1; (pline[pspc] == ' ' ||
                    pline[pspc] == '\t') && pspc < plen &&
                    pspc < tw; ++pspc) {
                        if (pline[pspc] == '\t') {
                            cantab = true;
                        }
                    }
                    // enough to warrant a tab stop?
                    if (col + pspc >= (col + tw)/tw*tw) {
                        cantab = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (pline[0] == '\t') {
                    cantab = true;
                }
            } // else we got EOF and those spaces have to stay
            if (cantab) {
                // pop the spaces and adjust current column accordingly
                while (len > 0 && line[--len] == ' ') {
                    --col;
                    line[len] = '\0';
                } // no need to fix len, as it gets reset below
            }
            printf("%s", line);
            len = plen;
            copy(line, pline);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* entab: process string from `s`, replace in-place spaces with tabs.
 * Assume '\0' terminated string. Relies on extern variable for column
 * alignment.
 * tw - tab width
 */
size_t entab(char s[], size_t tw)
{
    extern size_t col;  // current column
    extern size_t tcol; // target column
    size_t j = 0;
    bool gotnul = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; !gotnul; ++i) {
        // on blank or tab just continue reading and move our target
        // column forward
        if (s[i] == ' ') {
            ++tcol;
        }
        else if (s[i] == '\t') {
            tcol = (tcol+tw)/tw*tw;
        }
        else {
            // on non-blank char, if we're lagging behind target fill-up
            // with tabs & spaces and then write the char, else just
            // write the char
            if (tcol > col) {
                for (size_t at = (tcol/tw*tw-col/tw*tw)/tw; at > 0;
                --at) {
                    s[j] = '\t';
                    ++j;
                    col = (col+tw)/tw*tw;
                }
                for (size_t as = tcol-col; as > 0; --as) {
                    s[j] = ' ';
                    ++j;
                    ++col;
                }
            }
            s[j] = s[i];
            if (s[j] == '\0') {
                gotnul = true;
            }
            else {
                ++j;
                ++col;
                ++tcol;
            }
        }
    }
    return j;
}

/* getline: read a line into `s`, return string length;
 * `sz` must be >1 to accomodate at least one character and string
 * termination '\0'
 */
size_t getline(char s[], size_t sz)
{
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    bool el = false;
    while (i + 1 < sz && !el) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            el = true; // note: `break` not introduced yet
        }
        else {
            s[i] = (char) c;
            ++i;
            if (c == '\n') {
                el = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (i < sz) {
        if (c == EOF && !feof(stdin)) { // EOF due to read error
            i = 0;
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy a '\0' terminated string `from` into `to`;
 * assume `to` is big enough;
 */
void copy(char * restrict to, char const * restrict from)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; from[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
    to[i] = '\0';
}
```

### Test

#### Input

```
                                        sdas                
    a   a   aaa aasa      aaa               d   dfsdf           aaa ss  s       g
aa      asd        s    f   f  f    X   
         asf
```

Showing the tabs as `^I`:

```
$ cat -T test.txt 
                                        sdas                
    a   a   aaa aasa^I  aaa^I            d   dfsdf           aaa ss  s       g
aa^I  ^Iasd^I       s^If^If  f^IX  ^I
     ^I asf ^I^I^I ^I
```

#### Output

```
                                        sdas                
    a   a   aaa aasa      aaa               d   dfsdf           aaa ss  s       g
aa      asd        s    f   f  f    X   
         asf
```

Showing the tabs as `^I`:

```
$ cat -T out.txt 
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^Isdas^I^I^I^I
^Ia^Ia^Iaaa^Iaasa^I  aaa^I^I^I^Id^Idfsdf^I^I^Iaaa^Iss^Is^I^Ig
aa^I^Iasd^I^I   s^If^If  f^IX^I
^I^I asf^I^I^I^I
```

Comment: `gcc` has `-ansi`, `-std=c90`, or `-std=c89` instead of `-std=c99` if you want `c99` extensions to give you a warning/error.

Comment: I used to stick to ansi, but I kept getting comments how there are nice new features available so decided to move up to c99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP only asked a few direct questions.

> When either a tab or a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given preference?

Use *blanks* `' '`.

[Developers Who Use Spaces Make More Money Than Those Who Use Tabs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/)

---

> For lines that can fit in the buffer, the solution is straightforward. However, what if they can't?

Use a generous buffer.  **And** when the line does not fit in the buffer, exit with a failure message.

Let us go deeper ...

When memory was expensive, too often code used fixed size small buffers, leading to problems with expanded uses.

With cheap memory, code could be written to allow for re-allocated read buffers sizes, virtually unlimited yet technically limited to `SIZE_MAX`.

This value can readily exceed the memory capacity of the platform.

Now we live in an era of code security vs. hacking.  A program that allows external input to readily consume system  resources is a hacker target as part of an exploitation.  For the purpose of en-tabbing a line, why support 1 Gbyte long lines?  Say code limited lines to 1 MByte.  Yes once in a great while some application will die due to a *long* line and a Defect Report may ensue - and go to the bottom of the list in resolution handling.  Risk vs. reward: handling ever larger lines vs. greater exploitation risk.

In any case, C has an *Environmental limit*,

> An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character. The value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256.  C11dr §7.21.2 7

Any code working with lines much larger than `BUFSIZ` runs into that limitation and so risks UB.

I recommend:

- Use buffers 2x the largest expected need for that task.  In this case, consider `#define LINEBUF (BUFSIZ+1u)` or `#define LINEBUF (BUFSIZ*2u)` and allocate `char *line`.
- Treat long input as non-compliant and either reject the partial line and the rest of the line OR fail the code with a message.

Note: On many platforms, code can allocate very large buffers with `*alloc()` and not truly consume resources until needed.  [Why is malloc not “using up” the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359)
.

---

> For lines that can fit in the buffer, the solution is straightforward. However, what if they can't?  (Take 2)

*Entab* only requires about a few bytes.  Think [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  Re-write code.  See below.

---

> Other

**Conditions**

Conditions like `LINEBUF >= MAXTW` can be made into a compile time check

```
#if !(LINEBUF >= MAXTW)
  #error Buffer size too small
#endif
```

Also research [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c).

**Overview**

Nice format and good style.

**getline()**

[`ssize_t getline(char **, size_t *, FILE *)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is a popular *nix function that conflicts with OP's `size_t getline(char s[], size_t sz)`.  Consider a different name `my_getline()`.

Suggested alternative with, IMO, improvements. (Ignoring "`break` not introduced yet")

```
size_t my_getline(char s[], size_t sz) {
  if (sz <= 0) { // Handle this pathological case right away
    return 0;
  }
  sz--;

  int c = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i < sz && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    s[i++] = (char) c;
    if (c == '\n') {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (c == EOF && !feof(stdin)) { // EOF due to read error
    i = 0;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Note: OP's code has UB in the pathological case `sz == 1` as it tests uninitialized `c` with `c == EOF`.

**copy()**

Alternative code for consideration:

```
void copy(char * restrict to, char const * restrict from) {
  while ((*to++ = *from++));
}
```

**entab()**

Alternative code for consideration:

With the following there is no  limitation on tab width, line length (other than `int`).  No `LINEBUF` or `MAXTW` buffers needed.  Just 3 `int`.

```
#define PRT_TAB "^I"
#define TAB_WIDTH 4
#define FAVORRED ' '

void entab(FILE *istream) {
  int queued_spaces = 0;
  int tab_position = 0;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(istream))  != EOF) {
    if (ch == ' ') {
      queued_spaces++;
      tab_position++;
      if (tab_position == TAB_WIDTH) {
#if FAVORRED == '\t'
        putchar('\t');
#else
        if (queued_spaces == 1) putchar(' ');
        else fputs(PRT_TAB, stdout);
#endif
        queued_spaces = 0;
        tab_position = 0;
      }
    } else if (ch == '\t') {
      fputs(PRT_TAB, stdout);
      queued_spaces = 0;
      tab_position = 0;
    } else {
      while (queued_spaces > 0) {
        putchar(' ');
        queued_spaces--;
        tab_position++;
      }
      putchar(ch);
      tab_position++;
      tab_position %= TAB_WIDTH;
    }
  }
  while (queued_spaces > 0) {
    putchar(' ');
    queued_spaces--;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int ch;
  FILE *istream = fopen("Input", "rb");
  assert(istream);
  puts("Input");
  while ((ch = fgetc(istream))  != EOF) {
    putchar(ch);
  }
  rewind(istream);
  puts("");

  puts("Output");
  entab(istream);
  fclose(istream);
}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes agree about "state".  In fact the "state" size needed is O(tab width), not O(line width) - certainly a small  value.

Comment: @TobySpeight Hmmm, On 3rd thought, I think the entabbing can be done with `O(1)` space.  I suspect the code could be quite small.

Comment: Yes, buffer only requires `MAXTW` and the program demonstrates that already and doesn't need more. With `LINEBUF 2` it's crippled (blanks left-over), but multiple passes seem to yield the correct output because the "merge" part makes the tab eat the blank on each successive run. For extremely long lines my `col` counter could overflow and I guess we could mod it with `tw` to prevent that.

I like the assignments in conditionals but previously I got some comments they should be avoided so I tried to stay away from them. What is good practice with those?

Comment: @div0man Advice that recommends to not do something, yet lacks a candidate solution has some value, but not that much.  In general code for 1) functionality (it has to work right) 2) clarity (so you and others can review and improve) , 3) [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) efficiency and then 4) worry about linear performance improvements -like to mod or not to mod.  When pressed, drop #4.

Comment: @div0man See [How a stream error indicator affects following input code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53272650/2410359) for `ch==EOF && !feof(f)` details.

Comment: Interesting read, thanks. I've been pondering that little detail ever since you introduced it - should it even be in the `getline` or should the user of `getline` check whether it returned 0 due to EOF or error? The user must also deal with it properly. I think in some cases some of these exercises would continue reading after error. Great alternative code, I see how I made my solution complicated for no reason. Btw, shouldn't the `%=` go out of the conditional (think blanks-only lines)? What normally drives the decision whether to read char by char or in chunks like I did?

Comment: @div0man Yes, I should have coded `tab_position = (tab_position+ 1)%TAB_WIDTH;` in all places where `tab_position` is incremented.

Comment: @div0man Re: "The user must also deal with it properly." --> What is your suggested handling?  IMO, `getline()` should do the best it can without obliging too much on calling code.  Example, non-undefined-behavior even with foolish `sz <= 1`.  Do you want to add "Do not call `getline()` when `ferror(stdin)` true"?  IMO, just handle `ferror(stdin)` true on function entry  in a sensible fashion - as you have done.

Comment: @div0man Lastly, don't worry _too_ much about input errors, there are rare.  A simply way to get one is to read a stream that is opened for writing only.

Comment: Sorry I got confused for a sec. It was not related to the OP but to some other code I have where in some cases the code doesn't exit on 1st (technically, 2nd) EOF read (getline returns 0), but another call is made to getline, and that's when we exit. If the 1st was an error, the 2nd could be !=EOF and the code would continue to run and possibly have corrupt data creep into (partial) output instead of cleanly ending the output on first error. Those cases need to be treated from the outside, that's what I meant, but the !feof would still have to stay inside getline to prevent skipping over err.