# K&R Exercise 1-22. Fold (break) lines at specified column

Tags: beginner, c, strings, formatting, io

### Intro

I'm going through the K&R book (2nd edition, ANSI C ver.) and want to get the most from it: learn (outdated) C and practice problem-solving at the same time. I believe that the author's intention was to give the reader a good exercise, to make him think hard about what he can do with the tools introduced, so I'm sticking to program features introduced so far and using "future" features and standards only if they don't change the program logic.

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99`.

### K&R Exercise 1-22

Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th column of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.

### Solution

The solution attempts to reuse functions coded in the previous exercises (`getline` & `copy`) and make the solution reusable as well. In that spirit, a new function `size_t foldline(char * restrict ins, char * restrict outs, size_t fcol, size_t tw);` is coded to solve the problem. However, it requires a full buffer to be able to determine the break-point, so I coded `size_t fillbuf(char s[], size_t sz);` to top-up the buffer.

I wanted to make the folding non-destructive and possibly reversible, so the program doesn't delete anything, and adds a `\` when we break individual "words". The output can be reversed by deleting `(?<=\ )\n|(?<=\t)\n|\\\n` pattern matches (obviously if original had some matches, they'll get deleted too). Would you say this design approach is good?

In the spirit of writing reusable code, should I move appending the '\n' and '\' to the `main` routine and make the function just split the string at breakpoint? Or even, make one to find the breakpoint, and other to split the string?

```
## Code

/* Exercise 1-22. Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more
 * shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th
 * column of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very
 * long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXTW   16          // max. tab width
#define MAXFC   100         // max. fold column, must be >=MAXTW
#define LINEBUF MAXFC+2     // line buffer size, must be >MAXFC+1

size_t getline(char line[], size_t sz);
void copy(char * restrict to, char const * restrict from);
size_t foldline(char * restrict ins, char * restrict outs, size_t fcol,
 size_t tw); // style Q, how to indent this best?
size_t fillbuf(char s[], size_t sz);

int main(void)
{
    char line[LINEBUF];     // input buffer
    size_t len;             // input buffer string length

    size_t  fcol = 10;      // column to fold at
    size_t  tw = 4;         // tab width

    if (fcol > MAXFC) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (tw > MAXTW) {
        return -2;
    }

    len = getline(line, LINEBUF);
    while (len > 0) {
        char xline[LINEBUF];    // folded part
        size_t xlen;            // folded part string length

        // fold the line (or part of one)
        xlen = foldline(line, xline, fcol, tw);
        printf("%s", line);

        // did we fold?
        if (xlen > 0) {
            // we printed only the first part, and must run the 2nd part through
            // the loop as well
            copy(line, xline);
            if (line[xlen-1] == '\n') {
                len = xlen;
            }
            else {
                // if there's no '\n' at the end, there's more of the line and
                // we must fill the buffer to be able to process it properly
                len = fillbuf(line, LINEBUF);
            }
        }
        else {
            len = getline(line, LINEBUF);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Folds a line at the given column. The input string gets truncated to have
 * `fcol` chars + '\n', and the excess goes into output string.
 * Non-destructive (doesn't delete whitespace) and adds a '\' char before the
 * '\n' if it has to break a word. Can be reversed by deleting
 * "(?<=\ )\n|(?<=\t)\n|\\\n" regex pattern matches unless the original file had
 * matches as well.
 */
size_t foldline(char * restrict ins, char * restrict outs, size_t fcol,
 size_t tw)
{
    /* Find i & col such that they will mark either the position of termination
     * (\0 or \n) or whatever the char in the overflow column.
     * Find lnbi such that it will mark the last non-blank char before the
     * folding column.
     */
    size_t i;
    size_t lnbi;
    size_t col;
    char lc = ' ';
    for (col = 0, i = 0, lnbi = 0; ins[i] != '\0' && ins[i] != '\n' &&
     col < fcol; ++i) {
        if (ins[i] == ' ') {
            ++col;
            if (lc != ' ' && lc != '\t') {
                lnbi = i-1;
            }
        }
        else if (ins[i] == '\t') {
            col = (col + tw) / tw * tw;
            if (lc != ' ' && lc != '\t') {
                lnbi = i-1;
            }
        }
        else {
            ++col;
        }
        lc = ins[i];
    }

    // Determine where to fold at
    size_t foldat;
    if (col < fcol) {
        // don't fold, terminated before the fold column
        outs[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
    else if (col == fcol) {
        // maybe fold, we have something in the overflow
        if (ins[i] == '\n' || ins[i] == '\0') {
            // don't fold, termination can stay in the overflow
            outs[0] = '\0';
            return 0;
        }
        else if (lnbi > 0 || (ins[0] != ' ' && ins[0] != '\t' && (ins[1] == ' '
         || ins[1] == '\t'))) {
            // fold after the whitespace following the last non-blank char
            foldat = lnbi+2;
        }
        else {
            // fold at overflow
            foldat = i;
        }
    }
    else {
        // col > fcol only possible if ins[i-1] == '\t' so we fold and place the
        // tab on the next line
        foldat = i-1;
    }

    // Fold
    size_t j = 0, k;
    // add a marker if we're folding after a non-blank char
    if (ins[foldat-1] != ' ' && ins[foldat-1] != '\t') {
        outs[j++] = ins[foldat-1];
        ins[foldat-1] = '\\';
    }
    for (k = foldat; ins[k] != '\0'; ++j, ++k) {
        outs[j] = ins[k];
    }
    outs[j] = '\0';
    ins[foldat++] = '\n';
    ins[foldat] = '\0';
    return j;
}

/* continue reading a line into `s`, return total string length;
 * the buffer must have free space for at least 1 more char
 */
size_t fillbuf(char s[], size_t sz)
{
    // find end of string
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    }

    // not introduced in the book, but we could achieve the same by c&p
    // getline code here
    return i + getline(&s[i], sz-i);
}

/* getline: read a line into `s`, return string length;
 * `sz` must be >1 to accomodate at least one character and string
 * termination '\0'
 */
size_t getline(char s[], size_t sz)
{
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    bool el = false;
    while (i + 1 < sz && !el) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            el = true; // note: `break` not introduced yet
        }
        else {
            s[i] = (char) c;
            ++i;
            if (c == '\n') {
                el = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (i < sz) {
        if (c == EOF && !feof(stdin)) { // EOF due to read error
            i = 0;
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy a '\0' terminated string `from` into `to`;
 * assume `to` is big enough;
 */
void copy(char * restrict to, char const * restrict from)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; from[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
    to[i] = '\0';
}
```

### Testing

#### Output

`$ ./ch1-ex-1-22-02 <ch1-ex-1-22-02.c >out.txt`

```
/* 
Exercise 
1-22. 
Write a 
program 
to "fold" 
long 
input 
lines 
into two 
or more
 * 
shorter 
lines 
after the 
last 
non-blank 
character 
that 
occurs 
before 
the n-th
 * column 
of input. 
Make sure 
your 
program 
does 
something 
intellige\
nt with 
very
 * long 
lines, 
and if 
there are 
no blanks 
or tabs 
before 
the 
specified 
column.
 */

#include 
<stdio.h>
#include 
<stdbool.\
h>

#define 
MAXTW   
16      
    // 
max. tab 
width
#define 
MAXFC   
100     
    // 
max. fold 
column,
```

...

#### Reversibility

```
$ ./ch1-ex-1-22-02 <ch1-ex-1-22-02.c | perl -p -e 's/(?<=\ )\n|(?<=\t)\n|\\\n//g' | diff - ch1-ex-1-22-02.c
```

returns nothing :)

Comment: `getline()`  [UB in the pathological case sz == 1 as it tests uninitialized c with c == EOF](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/207498/29485).

Comment: Got it. Now I'm thinking that the code would continue to run past a read error in some cases, too (`fillbuf` gets an error and EOF, code continues, next `getline` reads something and program continues...)

Answer (score 1):

Only a small review.

> Would you say this design approach is good?

Yes.  I did have trouble following the code though. I was not able to find a test that failed the coding goal.

> In the spirit of writing reusable code, should I move appending the '\n' and '\' to the main routine and make the function just split the string at breakpoint?

Yes, moving that appending out of `foldline()` does make sense, yet "In the spirit of writing reusable code" I would move as much out of `main()` as reasonable too.  Perhaps an intervening function?

> Or even, make one to find the breakpoint, and other to split the string?

Yes, `foldline()` is lengthly and looses clarity with its length.

---

Minor stuff

**Avoid order of precedence problems**

Consider effect of `bigline[LINEBUF * 2]` does not double the size.  Use `()` when a `define` has an expression.

```
// #define LINEBUF MAXFC+2 
#define LINEBUF (MAXFC+2)
```

**Uninitialized object evaluation**

`getline()`  [UB in the pathological case sz == 1 as it tests uninitialized c with c == EOF](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/207498/29485).  Simply change

```
// int c;
int c = 0;
```

Comment: @div0man I'd leave this question unaccepted  for at least a number of days to encourage deeper answers.